# GPS Ublox Neo 6m issue with arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, tinygps

I started working on the Arduino UNO with GPS Ublox Neo 6m. I connect GPS with arduino based on the schematic diagram as well as the script. It didn't display any data in the serial monitor even though it blinks and one more I did outside the building. I don't know what is causing it not to display any data.

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop(){
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you properly connect the GPS module to VCC and GND and connected the TX of the GPS to the Arduino RX and vice versa? Also note that in my experience, many (if not most) cheap "Ublox" Neo 6M's sold [are actually counterfeit](https://portal.u-blox.com/s/question/0D52p00008HKEEECA5/psa-fake-ublox-modules-and-potential-ways-to-identify-them) and are of dubious quality, taking a very long time to get a first (or even subsequent) fix and not supporting many features of real Ublox GPS modules.